# Shorthand if statement always returns 'false' instead of value assigned

Tags: javascript, if-statement, arguments, conditional-operator

I am trying to use the shorthand if statement in Javascript to find out if one of my arguments is a negative number, and if it is, I want to change it to a specific value. Here is my code:

```
var findDigit = function(num, nth){
nth = nth < 0 ? nth === -1: nth;
}
```

I am trying to ask is if nth is *less than* 0, then change nth to -1, if it is *not* less than 0, do nothing, or keep nth the way that it is. When I console log the nth argument, I get 'false'.

I have run into this issue other times too. So I guess what I'm asking is, how do you write a shorthand if-statement without an 'else' section? I have a block of code I want it to run if the if-statement is *true*, but if it's false I don't want it to do anything. Thanks!

Comment: You probably meant just `-1` instead of `nth === -1`.

Comment: you are using the equality operator  in the if part, you just need to return -1 `var findDigit = function(num, nth){
nth = nth < 0 ? -1: nth;
}`

Comment: You have an assignment statement. The result of the `?` is assigned to `nth`. If `nth` is negative, you say that the result of the `?` is `nth === -1`, which might be true or false but is never `-1`. The `?` is not a shorthand `if` statement. It is an expression.

Comment: Check that you are not using `num` param in your function... It should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your if-statement: `nth < 0` the following code gets executed: `nth === -1` which is a check (including the type) if nth is exactly -1. Just omit this part and print

```
var findDigit = function(num, nth){
  nth = nth < 0 ? -1: nth;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, my mistake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything else than placing the values:

```
nth = nth < 0 ? -1: nth;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about javascript, but I feel that you are using comparison operator **===** that's why it is returning boolean(false) value.

Try using = for assigning value ie:
nth = nth < 0 ? nth = -1: nth;

Hope it helps.